# java.io.IOException: the device is not ready when trying to run JavaFX app with embedded javadb on other pc

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, javafx, derby

I have a JavaFX app with an embedded JavaDB, using JPA.

I have imported all the relevant libs & jars into my project and on my pc it works fine, in netbeans and outside netbeans.

But when I do a clean & build and I copy the dist folder to another pc (the database map is inside the dist folder) and I try to run the jar, I get the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: the device is not ready

This is my connection string:

> jdbc:derby:RaamProgDB;create=true [Leo on APP]

What is causing this?

Comment: in other machine cmd type `java -version` and compare to yours. Not sure how version might collide with derby, but JavaFX for example might not run if jre version is < 1.8u40. Can you try to build project on that other pc?

Comment: both versions are 1.8u40. And the other pc has no netbeans or such, I just want to run it without installing something else except the app.

Comment: You can get a lot more information from the exception; here's how: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain